# Strange bug in a while loop (C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, visual-c++, while-loop

I'm trying to make a program that works with a simple algorithm.

But for some reason, I get a strange bug (below is the simplified version of the program).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::string;

void find(int arr[], string name)
{
    int t = 8;
    int i = 0;
    int v = 0;

    // t should become equal to the smallest int of the array after this.


    while (arr[i])
    {
        if (arr[i] < t)
        {
            t = arr[i];
        }
        ++i;
    }

    /* When this statement below gets executed t gets what looks like a                 
    random value for some reason */
    cout << arr[t] << '\n';
    for (int b = 0; b < 2; ++b)
    {
        if (t == arr[b])
        {
            v = b;
        }
    }

    /* Again, arr[v] gets what looks like a random number */
    cout << "The cheapest " << name << " is number " << arr[v] << ".";
}



int main()
{

    /* [0] = "Cost for Steve"
       [1] = "Cost for Mark"
       [2] = "Cost for Andrew" */

    int cleaning[] = { 5, 4, 7 };
    int cooking[] = { 3, 6, 4 };
    int babysitting[] = { 7, 6, 3 };

    cout << "Number 1: Steve, Number 2: Mark, Number 3: Andrew.\n";

    find(cleaning, "cleaner");
    find(cooking, "cook");
    find(babysitting, "babysitter");




/* This is to prevent the console application from quitting */

    while (true)
    {

    }

}
```

I'm sure there is something wrong in the for and the while loop, but what?

If you're reading my code and some text or variable name seems foreign to you, chances are that I forgot to translate it (this is originally written in Italian).

Thanks for taking your time to read this.

EDIT: Thanks to @Tar I fixed the first part of the program, **but** the part which says `The (name) that costs less is n. (arr[v]).`still gives me a random number, I compiled and ran the program, the output is:

```
Number 1: Steve, Number 2: Mark, Number 3: Andrew.
4
The cheapest cleaner is number 4.
3
The cheapest cook is number 3.
3
The cheapest babysitter is number 7.
```

That is obviously wrong as it should say that the cheapest cleaner is number 2, the cheapest cook is number 1 and the cheapest babysitter is number 3.

PS: As soon as everything is fixed I will take the part which prints the cheapest price out.

Comment: In your function `find`, you pass `arr` as a parameter but then use `figo`. I'm guessing that's a mistake?

Comment: `figo` where is it defined?

Comment: What is "the strange bug"? Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Arrays are not terminated with a zero, unless they are string literals. You need to pass the array size as a parameter. (Or use `vector`.)

Comment: [WTH is `figo`??](http://whereswaldo.com/index.html#home)

Comment: ... or use a templated function that accepts the array size as an implicit template parameter.

Comment: By the way, the best way to fix this sort of problem WITHOUT posting it to stackoverflow, is to either cout the inner loop of your program (where it would have become clear it was reading past the end of the array), or use a step debugger.

Comment: I told you, I forgot to edit it, it's the original name for arr

Comment: Sorry guys, I can't believe I did not notice this, pardon.

Comment: The first call to `find` passes `cleaner`, but `cleaning` is allocated.

Comment: @donjuedo It's because I didn't translate it good enough, fixed it now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above all, I want to make a statement: I am not an English-speaker, so if I said wrong words, please excuse me.
I think this question is not very difficult. I fixed your algorithm and output format. Actually, I almost rewrote it.
In my view, your code seems kind of naive. If you only learnt C++ syntax, there is a long way to study algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int find(const vector<int>& numbers) {
    int minVul = numbers[0];
    int rank = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        if (minVul > numbers[i])
        {
            minVul = numbers[i];
            rank = i;
        }
    }
    return rank;
}



int main() {

    vector<string> name = { "steve","mark","andrew" };
    /* [0] = "Cost for steve"
    [1] = "Cost for mark"
    [2] = "Cost for andrew" */

    vector<int> cleaning = { 5, 4, 7 };
    vector<int> cooking = { 3, 6, 4 };
    vector<int> babysitting = { 7, 6, 3 };

    int cleaner = find(cleaning);
    cout << "Cleaning:" << name[cleaner] << " costs least in " << cleaning[cleaner] << endl;
    int cooker = find(cooking);
    cout << "Cooking:" << name[cooker] << " costs least in " << cooking[cooker] << endl;
    int babysitter = find(babysitting);
    cout << "Babysitter:" << name[babysitter] << " costs least in " << babysitting[babysitter] << endl;

    system("pause"); //This is a common skill to prevent the console application from quitting.
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Cleaning:mark costs least in 4
Cooking:steve costs least in 3
Babysitter:andrew costs least in 3
```

Comment: I know about system("pause") but using a simple while (true) seems cleaner to me.

Comment: After a bit of trying to fully understand this code, I gotta say this is much cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is within your first `while` loop in `find`:

```
while (arr[i]) // while the element at arr[i] is NOT 0
{
    if (arr[i] < t)
    {
        t = arr[i];
    }
    i++;
}
```

Here you continuously evaluate elements in `arr` for whether they are not `0`. This is not correct. You've declared your arrays as:

```
int cleaning[3] = { 5, 4, 7 };
int cooking[3] = { 3, 6, 4 };
int babysitting[3] = { 7, 6, 3 };
```

None of these contain `0`, so your `while` loop will run indefinitely and you'll be reading past the memory for each array which is not good news.

Consider using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, and see how much clearer and safer your code becomes:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void find(const std::vector<int>& numbers)
{
    auto t = 8;
    // Look through each element in the container:
    for(auto number : numbers)
    {
        if (number < t)
        {
            t = number;
        }
    }
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> cleaning = {5, 4, 7};
    find(cleaning);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but when trying to compile this it gives me 3 compiler errors about t, also I'ver heard about 'auto' and 'vectors', but I've never learned what they are.

Comment: Can you please give me a tip on how to correct the issues?